# At which of the following lines does reading data happen in SQLite android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
1    Cursor resultSet = mydatbase.rawQuery("Select * from TutorialsPoint",null);
2    String password1 = resultSet.getString(1);
3    String password2 = resultSet.getString(1);
```

Do all the rows get read from DB and stored in resultSet when the 1st line is executed(in other words do 2nd and 3rd lines simply output the already retreived values)?

Or is data that will be stored in password2 read from the database at line 3

Comment: There is no difference between 2 and 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above.

```
Cursor resultSet = mydatbase.rawQuery("Select * from TutorialsPoint",null);
```

At this point, the query has not been executed. It is stored inside the `Cursor`.

```
String password1 = resultSet.getString(1);
```

At this point, the query is executed. You then crash, as the `Cursor` is not positioned on a row, because you have not called `moveToFirst()` or any other `moveTo...()` method.

```
String password2 = resultSet.getString(1);
```

This statement will never be executed, due to the aforementioned crash.

In other words, the query is lazy-executed. Only when you perform an operation on the `Cursor` that needs the result set will the query actually be executed. This is a pain for multi-threaded development.

Comment: If the result of the SQL statement contains millions of rows and will take a long time to be totally read from the Database, can I still call cursor.moveToLast() and get only the last row?   

I'm creating a WhatsApp like application (lot of messages but retrieve only latest unless needed)

Comment: @SadeepDarshana: "can I still call cursor.moveToLast() and get only the last row?" -- no. "I'm creating a WhatsApp like application (lot of messages but retrieve only latest unless needed)" -- then use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, along with a better choice of `ORDER BY` direction, to retrieve only a subset of rows.

Comment: @CommonsWare, there is no need to use `LIMIT`, since Cursors in android are 'windowed', that is, they have limited amount of data and fill in themselves as needed

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev: Personally, I still recommend using `LIMIT`, as your business rules may result in better efficiency than relying on windows. If nothing else, though, the sort order should be changed, so that the first rows are the ones of interest, not the last ones. I do not know how efficient `moveToLast()` is in a windowed situation ("millions of rows").